# SVN Possibly Corrupting my Binary Jar files?

Tags: java, svn

At work yesterday I committed an Java Applet Jar file to our svn project. The project manager pushed it out for me, but when it's on production the file fails. I can open the jar and the classes look fine.

Could SVN be doing this? I don't use svn, I'm just trying to figure out why it works on my dev, but comes out corrupted on production? Maybe a text/binary setting or something?

Comment: What error is generated when the JAR file fails? This would help to diagnose the problem. As @grantk says, I've never had any corruption issues storing binaries in SVN.

Comment: If the file was corrupted, I don't believe it would be useable. Try unpacking the archive (if you can do this the jar is file) but you might like to check the modifcation dates of the files to ensure they match what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't be storing binaries (e.g. JARs) in Subversion.  Use an artifact management tool such as Artifactory, Nexus or Archiva.  You can access the artifacts via Maven, Ant/Ivy, or a variety of other tools.  Releases (e.g. WARs) are just URLs given to your release manager.

SVN can corrupt a binary if incorrectly set to text, but that's unusual.  I believe *.jar would default to binary, not text, unless someone is doing things by hand incorrectly.

I usually verify JAR/WAR files are ok by just copying, changing the extension to .zip, and opening them up.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using svn for storing jar files for many years and deploy to production right from my svn checkout and have never had an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check md5 of your local copy + on production

```
openssl dgst /path/to/your/file
```

Or you have some issue with privileges? Try to omit SVN in order to deploy on production and then check whether everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I would very much doubt it. 
Have you looked at the comparative filesizes etc ensure all the file has been transferred

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. @DaveRead I get a NoClassFoundException, this is the same error I would receive if I tried to run a blank/garbage Jar file. @Peter Lawrey Yes, I can open it manually like a zip file, but it' wont run.

I should also mention that, they tried "reverting" the file to a known working Version, with no luck. So I'm trying to run down possible scenarios of what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While SVN will not corrupt your files *by design*, it is not totally unthinkable that something goes wrong along the way and you end up with corrupted files.

So in general, when you encounter corrupted files you are affected by either

- unexpected effects of data thanges that SVN performs by design (e.g. `svn:eol-style` keywords)
- faulty hardware (bad harddisk?)
- bugs in the operating system or its file system; see for example [this description of afile corruption bug in Windows 7](http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/entries/3-Windows-7-Bogus-ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT-error?s=6767f389f01f752c60f10a2ebb4bf3ee).